# Is there a tensorflow version of scipy.optimize.curve_fit and scipy.integrate.cumtrapz functions?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, scipy

I'm new to Python and TensorFlow, so I need help. I would like to know if there is any version of these two functions in TensorFlow: `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` and `scipy.integrate.cumtrapz`.

I've already written some code using `numpy` arrays but, now I have to work with Tensor inside an existing TensorFlow project, so I have to convert my code, which uses this two functions, in TensorFlow. I'm having problems in finding a way to 'translate' them. I'm not able to find out if there is a simple way to do it.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: It might help if you could add a bit more information, like an example of you existing scipy code. A simple solution could be to keep your code as it is, scipy and tensorflow can be mixed in the same project.